# SonarQube showing 0% code coverage in node js application

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, istanbul

I have installed sonar Qube and integrated it with node js application.
Right now I am getting code coverage as zero so I created a sonar properties file as below

```
sonar.projectKey=MyApp
sonar.login=[token]

sonar.sources=.

#sonar.exclusions=app/node_modules/*,app/coverage/lcov-report/*

# coverage reporting
sonar.javascript.coveragePlugin=lcov
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=app/coverage/lcov.info
```

but still my code coverage is coming as 0 %

Any Idea how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some information gaps that we should fill in so that I can help you better, like, when you're trying to get coverage? You're using some kind of CI/CD pipeline?

Despite this, I had a similar problem a while back and I believe it might help, it turns out that when you use sonarcloud in some pipeline the code that is scanned by the sonar is the difference between the source code and yours.

So if you add or change code which is not covered by test setup it will show code coverage as no information and if you add or change code covered it will show a percentage just referring to changed code.

I will also share with you my sonar setup from a personal project, hope it helps.

```
sonar.projectKey=some_organization_algorithms-data-structures
sonar.organization=some_organization
sonar.projectName=Algorithms and Data Structures
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.tests=__tests__
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

Comment: I am writing to setup and see code coverage in my local. The last property where you have specified lcov.info. Di you create this folder and file first ?

Comment: No, it will be created during the run process. Could you show your test config file and the structure of your project?